# Wordpress: Find which plugin is being updated

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin in which I need to do some action when a plugin is updated, I have used `add_action('upgrader_post_install', 'myFunction')`.

In `myFunction` I need to get what plugin is being updated at that instance and details of version changes of that plugin.

I have been looking over internet but couldn't find any info regarding this.

Any suggestions on how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some good amount of time, I got my answer

`add_filter('upgrader_post_install','myFunction', 5, 3);`

with 3 parameters for myFunction gives updating file details from where we can get version

`myFunction($t1,$t2,$t3){
//$t2 & $t3 gives info about files being updated
}`